# What happens if you don't take the supplies from the car?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

This question contains major plot and ending spoilers. Seriously, don't read any more if you plan to ever play this game.

> When you find Clementine at the end of the game, it turns out that the person she's been talking to was the owner of the car from which you choose to either take the supplies or leave them.  In my play-through, I took them.  Now, the only reason he gives for everything he's done is that you took his supplies. So what happens if you don't? Is the *stranger* another person altogether? Does he give another reason for stalking you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing significant changes.

> It doesn't matter if you don't take the supplies by the end of chapter 2, the rest of your group will take them anyway without you (one of will hand Clementine a battery). The stranger will say you took supplies from his car, Lee will respond by saying he didn't take but his group did and the stranger will say Lee didn't do anything to stop them.

Comment: So choices don't really matter at all! :(

Comment: It bummed me as well. Since I was "punished" even though in my playthrough I avoided looting the car, it felt like I was being punished for something I had nothing to do with and was actually against.

Comment: Actually that's not totally true, if Lee didn't take the food from the car and say it to the stranger, he will reply that's what Clem said to him and so Lee was ok, but then explain that Lee still made choices that putted Clem's Life in danger and so must be taken away from him.

Comment: @jmfsg The whole choices thing is kinda a lie. No single choice does really make a difference later, because the game has just one plot and no choice affects the plot. If you rescue someone different, then you just have a slightly different dialog, that is all. But the end result of the chapter and the game as a whole will be the same. Telltale straight out lied to us here.